# Twitter get user info without authenticate - Possible?

Tags: c#, authentication, twitter

Is there any chance to get a users image, latest post and name without the need of authenticate? Cuz I know I can find my own twitter if i go twitter.com/nameOfMyTwitterAccount
So any ideas? Using TweetSharp atm in C#

Comment: I don't think it is possible without some hacks. When you are using the Twitter web UI you are using Twitter's application under their supervision if you will. When you want to use your own application there are certain rules.

Comment: Do you mean user authentication or your app authentication?

Comment: I dont want authenticate with a user, just want their info. For example a public group in facebook. but this time i want the same for Twitter.

Comment: I don't want the user to "log in " eachtime to see other peoples usernames etc.

Comment: then as long as you have authenticated your app you can use https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/lookup this will allow you to get the public info of users

Comment: @PatrickEvans - Do you have any ideas how to go further?
How do I get users info like tweets, Image etc?